# Persian Characters in URL (with Alamofire)

Tags: swift, post, request, alamofire

i have variables and i want put them in url to post
some variables can be persian or english characters
everything is well when characters are english
but when i use persian characters alamofire respond invalid url
the code is .

> let headers : Dictionary = [
>               "Content-Type":"application/json"
>           ];
>           let request = Product_Rename() . 
>           request.newName = string .

```
    request.productId = UInt(_Data[deletIndex].ProductId!)
    Alamofire.request("http://example.com/api/product/rename?productId=\(_Data[deletIndex].ProductId!)&newName=\(string)&AUTHID=\(authID!)",
        method: .put,
        headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString(completionHandler: {response in

        })
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data:data,encoding:.utf8){
                    let x = Product_Rename_Response(json:utf8Text)
                    if x.success == true {
                        self._Data[self.deletIndex].Name = string
                        self._ProductTable.reloadData()
                    }else{
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the special characters from the URL.

```
request.productId = UInt(_Data[deletIndex].ProductId!)
let url = "http://example.com/api/product/rename?productId=\(_Data[deletIndex].ProductId!)&newName=\(string)&AUTHID=\(authID!)"
if let encodedUrl = original.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) {
    Alamofire.request(encodedUrl,
    method: .put,
    headers: headers)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseString(completionHandler: {response in

    })
    // use the data
}
```

The method `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` will encode the characters into [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (e.g. `https://example.com/foo.php?text=bar%20baz`, where `%20` represents a space).